# is there any light-weight http request library for iphone?

Tags: iphone, http, asihttprequest

I know ASIHTTPRequest, but it's too powerful for me. actually, I nerver use some functions it provided. It also has too much dependences.

I also know NSURLConnection, I don't like it, either.

Do I have some other choice??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the [AFNetworking](http://engineering.gowalla.com/2011/10/24/afnetworking/) library for iOS, an alternative to ASIHTTPRequest.

Answer (score 4):

Don't like it, whats there not to like. ASIHttpRequest is about the easiest to implement. Only thing easier is using object `initWithContentsOfURL` method:

```
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://some.url/file.ext"]];
```

But you should really looking into something like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), because ASIHttpRequest is no longer being developed by it creator.
AFNetworking is really powerful and uses blocks, which keep your coding to a minimum.

Answer (score 2):

ASIHTTPRequest isn't just overkill, it's also [officially abandoned and deprecated by its developer](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;). People don't seem to know this, so please help get the word out.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) seems to be the heir apparent, though it has competitors.